# Kivy size_hint not working for all Layouts

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I was just learning Kivy from Youtube, and The size_hint attribute in all layouts, buttons, widgets is not working. How do I fix this issue?

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse,Color,Line
from random import randint

class PaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        rootWindow=Widget()
        self.painter=PaintWindow()
        # clearBtn=Button(text="Clear",color=(1,0,0,1),font_size="30sp",background_color=(0,1,0,1),pos =(300, 250))  
        print(f"SIZE OF PAINTER: {self.painter.width},{self.painter.height}")
#####################################################################################################
        '''
        This Button's size_hint is not working on running on my device or due to some kivy issue.
        '''
        clearBtn = Button(text="Clear Screen",size_hint=(0.2,0.2),pos_hint=(0.8,0.8))

#####################################################################################################
        clearBtn.bind(on_release=self.clearCanvas)
        rootWindow.add_widget(self.painter)
        rootWindow.add_widget(clearBtn)
        return rootWindow
    def clearCanvas(self,obj):
        print(obj)
        self.painter.canvas.clear()
class PaintWindow(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.canvas.add(Color(rgb=(randint(0,255)/255,randint(0,255)/255,randint(0,255)/255)))
        # d=20
        # self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d)))
        touch.ud['line']= Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y),width=5)
        self.canvas.add(touch.ud['line'])
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points+=[touch.x,touch.y]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PaintApp().run()
```

I'm a complete beginner at kivy. Here is an image of Kivy window I get as an output:

[image: Image of Kivy window I get as an output]

I wanted it to get on kind of to the top right corner of screen.

I tried it in kvlang but still showing the same result.

Comment: Using words like "ASAP" is considered rude here. See "[Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)" for more details.

Comment: In general, posts written with care and research are upvoted. In general, posts that are dashed off like a Facebook post (complete with words like "plz") tend to attract downvotes. Readers seem to like effort and precision here.

Answer (score 1):

The `size_hint` does work for `Layouts`, but `Widget` is not a `Layout`. The `Layout` that interprets the `size_hint` is the `Layout` that contains the `Widget` with the `size_hint`. So, when you provide a `size_hint` to a `Button`:

```
clearBtn = Button(text="Clear Screen",size_hint=(0.2,0.2),pos_hint=(0.8,0.8))
```

The `size_hint` is not used by the `Button` itself, it is used by the `Layout` when you do something like:

```
l.add_widget(clearBtn)
```

where `l` is a `Layout`. If you do:

```
rootWindow.add_widget(clearBtn)
```

The `size_hint` will not be honored, because `rootWindow` is a `Widget`, but not a `Layout`. Try defining `rootWindow` as:

```
rootWindow = RelativeLayout()
```

Comment: But Even If I Changed The Inheritance PaintWindow(FloatLayout): it is not working..

Comment: You are not adding the `Button` to `PaintWindow`, you are adding it to `rootWindow`, which is not a `Layout`.